# How do I parse a long number string to just a number?

Tags: javascript

I have some Ids I need converted from strong to numbers however whenever I use parseInt() or Number(), I get a double type decimal

```
1.01038295007818e+016.0
```

I need to just convert the string to just a number.

Comment: Can you Just mention the string you want to convert to number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseInt()` function takes the first number of the string and removes decimal places, it returns an integer:

```js
var a = parseInt("1.000350001");
var b = parseInt("456789.1");
var c = parseInt("20");

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

The `Math.floor()` method rounds a number downward to its nearest integer:

```js
var d = Math.floor("1234.00101");

console.log(d);
```

The `Number()` function converts the string to a number that represents the strings value:

```js
var e = Number("1000.12");

console.log(e);
```

For your question, I believe either `parseInt` or `Math.floor` would work just fine, unless your number is greater than JavaScripts [largest available number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Answer was number is too big! Thanks for the extra informative answer though!

Answer (score 5):

The maximum integer that can be represented in javascript, without losing any precision, is `9007199254740991`. See [the javascript docs for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). If you want to use integers bigger than that, you will need to use a third party library like [Big Integer](https://silentmatt.com/biginteger/).

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 different ways to convert string to number as below:

parseInt(num); // default way (no radix)

parseInt(num, 10); // parseInt with radix (decimal)

parseFloat(num) // floating point

Number(num); // Number constructor

~~num //bitwise not

num / 1 // diving by one

num * 1 // multiplying by one

num - 0 // minus 0

+num // unary operator "+"

You will find thye explanation [Here](https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls)

for

```
var s = parseInt("101038295007818e0160",10); 
alert(s);
```

O/P: 101038295007818e0160 .

and for:

```
 var s = parseInt(101038295007818e0160,10); 
alert(s);
```

O/P:1

for

```
 var s = parseInt("101038295007818e0160"); 
alert(s);
```

O/P: 101038295007818e0160 .

and for:

```
 var s = parseInt(101038295007818e0160); 
alert(s);
```

O/P:1

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is scientific notation, because the number you've tried to parse it too big.

The largest integer accurately represented in Javascript is

```
9007199254740991
```

However your number `1.01038295007818e+016.0` is

```
10103829500781800
```